# How to set Android screen, resolution, aspect ratio and size in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm using ReactNative and Android. I am using style-components for css

As a result of designing with styled-component, the aspect ratio fits well on my device, but when tested with another device, the screen is broken or the ratio does not match.

So, what I am curious about is what method is the best way to use the same aspect ratio, resolution, and screen size to fit all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-screen`
for responsive UI. Just use wp('10%') or hp('20%') wherever possible.